# Qt creator can not include opencv header files

Tags: qt, opencv

I have downloaded qt-5.0.0 for windows.

http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.1/qt-windows-opensource-5.0.1-msvc2010_32-x86-offline.exe

I have added INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include in the .pro file.

Opencv 2.4.3 is already installed.

When I include header file in qtcreator :

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

There is compilation error : can not find opencv2/opencv.hpp

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. In Qt Creator, goto Projects on the left pane ( ctrl+5), then Build Environment -> Use System Environment, click on Details. Edit LIB variable. Add  here.

Comment: What do you add in LIB variable?

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- does `C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\opencv.hpp` actually exist?
- does the compile command (which you can check in the Qt Creator "compile output" window) show `-IC:\opencv\build\include` argument in the compile command?
- qmake should be run automatically after modifying the .pro file, but re-run it manually just in case (for example from Build menu), as suggested by the first answer
- this should not have any effect in issue like this, but just in case: if you are using "shadow build" (which is a good idea), make sure the source dir is clean of any generated files

Answer (score 0):

The correct header files are:

```
<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

… and so on. The include of "opencv.h" is deprecated!
It also does not work anymore for QtCreator auto-completion.

The solution is to update your sources to use the correct header files.

Answer (score 0):

After any change made to `.pro` file , Do right-click on `project folder` and click on run `qmake` .

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just ran into this problem tonight. luckily enough, after taking a fair time, the solution was found. If your project is managed by qmake, and Qcreator is used, just go to the `Build->Run qmake`, then build and run your project. A tip, whenever you change your `*.pro` file, remember to rerun `Build->Run qmake`, because that will reconfigure your project.
If this helps you, please give me a thumb up :)