# How to use OpenCV 3.2 in Qt-creator 4.2.1 in Windows plattform

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv

I want to use the OpenCV library 3.2 with Qt-creator 4.2.1 in Windows plattform.

In the .pro file I used the following code:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include
LIBS += LC:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x64/vc14/lib \
-opencv_world320d \
-opencv_world320 \
```

And in the main.cpp file I use:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
```

When I run my program I have the following error:

```
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to link OpenCV to QT creator on Windows 10 in a correct way?
Thank you in advance!

Note:
I already saw these tutorials/answers but nothing helps until now:

- [Qt creator can not include opencv header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683818/qt-creator-can-not-include-opencv-header-files?rq=1)
- [How to link opencv in QtCreator and use Qt library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library?rq=1)
- [Using OpenCV on Qt Creator 3.2 (Qt 5.3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kL0qfuLqB0U)
- [Using OpenCV on Qt Creator 3.2 (Qt 5.3) - Blog](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/11/using-opencv-3-qt-creator-3-2-qt-5-3/)
- And many others but they use old versions of OpenCV and/or Qt and/or Operating system